# How to get the specified option flag from within OptionParser

Tags: ruby, flags, optionparser

I'd like to get the exact option flag that was specified on the command line from within Ruby's OptionParser.

For example, suppose I have the following code:

```
parser = OptionParser.new {                                                                                                 
  |opts|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  opts.on('-f', '--file FILE', 'filename') {                                                                                            
    |arg|                                                                                                                   
    $filename = arg                                                                                                 
    # Here I'd like to know whether '-f' or '--file' was entered
    # on the command line.                                                                              
  }
  # ... etc. ...
}
```

I'd like to know whether the user happened to type '-f' or '--file' on the command line. Is this possible without writing two separate `opts.on` blocks?

Comment: Wait, but why??

Comment: @ndn user’s behaviour analysis? :)

Comment: @mudasobwa, on a CLI? xd

Comment: Please do not format block params that way. The fact that ruby allows it does not mean you should scoff your code readers.

Comment: Aside from the block formatting reminder, which I appreciate, can I assume that there is no way to do what I am asking, without a second opts.on block? I have my own idiosyncratic reasons for wanting to know this info :) ... but if it's not possible within the current implementation of OptionParser, I can live without it.

Comment: It probably is possible if you read the source and do some stuff like access local variables from the binding of the caller, but it obviously shouldn't be done.

Comment: the only other way I see is the read the `ARGV` before your parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get the flags being passed in when inside the `OptionParser.new` block. At that point it's too late. However, prior to OptionParser parsing the command-line, it's possible to look and see what's being passed in.

`ARGV` contains the raw command-line. For instance, if this is the command-line invocation for some code:

```
foo -i 1 -j 2
```

then `ARGV` will contain:

```
["-i", "1", "-j", "2"]
```

and, then it becomes pretty easy to grab the flags:

```
ARGV.grep(/^-/) # => ["-i", "-j"]
```

There are other OptionParser-like tools for Ruby, and those might let you access the flags being used, but I can't think of a reason I'd ever care to. Looking at your code it seems like you're not understanding how to use OptionParser:

```
parser = OptionParser.new {                                                                                                 
  |opts|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  opts.on('-f', '--file FILE', 'filename') {                                                                                            
    |arg|                                                                                                                   
    $filename = arg                                                                                                 
    # Here I'd like to know whether '-f' or '--file' was entered
    # on the command line.                                                                              
  }
  # ... etc. ...
}
```

Instead of doing it that way, I'd write it:

```
options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  opts.on('-f', '--file FILE', 'filename') { |arg| options[:filename] = arg }
end.parse!

if options[:filename]
  puts 'exists' if File.exist?(options[:filename])
end
```

Then, later in your code you can check in the `options` hash to see if either of the `-f` or `--file` options was given, and what the value was. That it was one or the other of `-f` or `--file` shouldn't ever matter.

If it does then you need to differentiate between the two flags, instead of treating them as if they're aliases:

```
options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  opts.on('-f', 'filename') { |arg| options[:f] = arg }
  opts.on('--file FILE', 'filename') { |arg| options[:file] = arg }
end.parse!

if options[:file] || options[:f]
  puts 'exists' if File.exist?(options[:file] || options[:f])
end
```

Comment: Yes, I have been doing something similar to this. I see that getting the exact option flag is not possible. I have my own, idiosyncratic reasons for wanting to get the exact flag value, and so I have abandoned OptionParser for this particular application, and I simply parse the command-line arguments "by hand" (i.e., by traversing ARGV myself in this case).